# create executable jar file when making businessobjects SAP BI SDK app

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

Hi I am writing a small SDK app for businessobjects (SAPBI 4.1).  I am using Java and I want to use the BOE scheduling functionality. I have a question -  I am implementing the IProgramBase class, which has a run() method.  I am told that I do not need a main method, and that it is good to create an executable jar from the program.  So my question is a general one - how can I create an executable jar without a main method?

Thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of the Business Objects Enterprise Framework, you only need your class to implement `IProgramBase` for the scheduler to run it.

However, with a normal JAR file, the only way is having a class (for example `com.example.MainClass`) with a `main` method so you can create a Manifest File (`MANIFEST.MF`) with these lines:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.example.MainClass
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not need to be runnable.  Just compile it as a normal jar without a main() method.